# How redirect from subdomain to other domains URI?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns

Is there any DNS or `.htaccess` (or combination of a two) solution for this type of redirection:

`blog.mydomain.com` point to `medium.com/my-publication`

And yes I am trying to apply this specifically to medium.com publication so if SSL certification or any other environmental conditions are relevant you check how it handles it. I have full control of my domain on the other side.

I am looking preferably into DNS solution because I will not be able to test `.htaccess` for a while.

Comment: DNS can't do any redirection, it can only resolve names to ip addresses. For HTTP redirects you need an application, for example any web server will do, and it should be simple to setup. On the other way, _some_ DNS provider will offer this as a service - since it does not require lots of resources they will basically run a tiny web server for you (seems like they often call it "[dns url forwarding](https://www.google.com/search?q=dns+url+forwarding)")

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I know the only relevant DNS record would be a `CNAME` record, and it would only allow redirecting the entire subdomain to medium.com.

```
NAME                    TYPE    VALUE
-------------------------------------------
blog.mydomain.com.      CNAME   medium.com.
```

To redirect to a specific URL, `.htaccess` would be needed, or a webserver that returns a redirect. If it were me, I'd setup a redirect for that specific article:

```
blog.mydomain.com/my-publication => medium.com/my-publication
```

But this requires a webserver being setup at blog.mydomain.com.

Comment: do I setup blog.mydomain.com in dns or in htaccess

Comment: You need `blog.mydomain.com` to be setup in DNS if you don't have it already setup, and a redirect for the specific URL.